# Json Properties Null - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have the following model

```
public class SocioEconomicStudy : BaseModel
{
    public string Folio { get; set; }

    public string Craft { get; set; }

    public string RequestType {get;set;}
}
```

And I send the following json

```
{
     "folio" : "folio",
     "craft" : "craft,
     "request_type": "request_type"
}
```

But when received the properties with underscore are null, I've tried camel case Pascal case, but only with the lowercase + underscores is that the properties without underscore work.

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] SocioEconomicStudy study)
{
    var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    _logger.LogInformation((study != null).ToString());
    _context.SocioEconomicStudyRepository.AddAsync(study, cancellationToken);
}
```

So only the properties without underscore are persisted, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What json serializer do you use?

Comment: @RubenVardanyan I'm using the default serializer,

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to `Startup.cs` solved my problem

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
         });
```

Now it accepts camelCase keys

Answer (score 2):

For the properties which not follow the naming rules you can add `JsonProperty` attribute, in your case your model should look like this

```
public class SocioEconomicStudy : BaseModel
{
    public string Folio { get; set; }

    public string Craft { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("request_type")]
    public string RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my model changes, or I need more models, I will also need to annotate every property with more than one word.

Comment: Yes you need to annotate every property or change the frontend part to send property named camel case